# PyQt5 реализация контекстного меню у виджетов выводимых через цикл

Tags: python, pyqt5

Пытаюсь реализовать последовательный вывод текстовых данных (из цикла) через виджет QLabel с возможностью вызова у каждого элемента контекстного меню, к сожалению при моем способе реализации выдается значение "последнего" меню созданного в цикле, а не того, по которому был совершен клик. Возможно ли вообще реализовать подобное таким образом?

```
class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    # окно приложения
    def initUI(self):
        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.textListBox = QVBoxLayout()

        #вызов подгрузки данных в окно приложения
        self.loadDateData()

        verticalBox = QVBoxLayout()
        verticalBox.addLayout(self.textListBox)

        centralWidget.setLayout(verticalBox)
        self.show()

   # подгрузка данных в окно приложения
   def loadDateData(self):
        for n in range(10):
            textLbl = QLabel('text' + str(n))

            self.menu = QMenu()
            action = QAction("Пункт меню" + str(n), self)
            action.triggered.connect(self.anyfunction)
            self.menu.addAction(action)

            textLbl.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
            textLbl.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu)

            # добавление сформированного виджета в QVBoxLayout
            self.textListBox.addWidget(textLbl)

   # отображаем меню при клике на блоке текста
   def on_context_menu(self):
        self.menu.exec_(QCursor.pos())
```

Comment: так вы ведь в `on_context_menu` вызываете `self.menu.`, а оно в цикле всегда последним будет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, в текущей случае, больше подойдет `Qt.ActionsContextMenu`, а не `Qt.CustomContextMenu`:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel, QAction, Qt, QMessageBox, QApplication


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    # Окно приложения
    def initUI(self):
        self.textListBox = QVBoxLayout()

        # Вызов подгрузки данных в окно приложения
        self.loadDateData()

        verticalBox = QVBoxLayout()
        verticalBox.addLayout(self.textListBox)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(verticalBox)

        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

    # Подгрузка данных в окно приложения
    def loadDateData(self):
        for n in range(10):
            label = QLabel('text' + str(n))
            label.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)

            action = QAction("Пункт меню " + str(n), self)
            action.triggered.connect(self._on_action_click)

            label.addAction(action)

            # Добавление сформированного виджета в QVBoxLayout
            self.textListBox.addWidget(label)

    def _on_action_click(self):
        action = self.sender()

        QMessageBox.information(self, None, action.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = Example()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

Вариант через `Qt.CustomContextMenu`:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel, QCursor, Qt, QMessageBox, QApplication, QMenu


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    # Окно приложения
    def initUI(self):
        self.textListBox = QVBoxLayout()

        # Вызов подгрузки данных в окно приложения
        self.loadDateData()

        verticalBox = QVBoxLayout()
        verticalBox.addLayout(self.textListBox)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(verticalBox)

        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

    # Подгрузка данных в окно приложения
    def loadDateData(self):
        for n in range(10):
            label = QLabel('text' + str(n))
            label.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)

            menu = QMenu()
            action = menu.addAction("Пункт меню " + str(n))
            action.triggered.connect(self._on_action_click)

            label.customContextMenuRequested.connect(lambda pos, menu=menu: self._on_context_menu(menu))

            # Добавление сформированного виджета в QVBoxLayout
            self.textListBox.addWidget(label)

    def _on_action_click(self):
        action = self.sender()

        QMessageBox.information(self, None, action.text())

    def _on_context_menu(self, menu):
        menu.exec_(QCursor.pos())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = Example()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас, такой способ работает, только одно но - контекстное меню появляется в стилях QLabel - это как-то можно изменить?

Comment: А у вас там style sheet где-то используется? И вы про стиль говорили для первого ведь способа? А у второго также?

Comment: да, используется, второй способ только увидел, сейчас посмотрим, спасибо

Comment: Спасибо - второй способ - именно то, что нужно!

Comment: @ANTiK, что-то сомневаюсь... разве что через стили до меню QLabel добираться, но он скорее всего для ActionsContextMenu создает и показывает меню через метод http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuEvent Так что ... хз :) Можно, конечно и свою реализацию contextMenuEvent делать, чтобы свое меню создавать, но не думаю что это лучше других вариантов

Comment: в методе _on_action_click мы через self.sender() получаем название элемента контекстного меню, а как-то возможно передать в этот метод уникальный идентификатор текста qlabel? Просто через отправку переменных получаем так же айди последнего элемента а не того, по которому кликнули

Comment: @ANTiK, тогда, создайте сами связь -- через словарь. В loadDateData этот словарь будете заполнять, ключом будет action, а значением -- label. После чего в _on_action_click имея action вы сможете из словаря получить label. Все просто

Comment: как-то очень подобное решение костылем попахивает, вроде тривиальная задача - динамический вывод текстовых блоков с возможностью их редактировать/удалять - неужели нет более "изящных" решений?

Comment: Не вижу тут ничего костыльного. Более изящные решения были бы через qlistview / qlistwidget / qgraphicsscene, но вы решили через qlabel + q*layout + qmenu + qaction делать, поэтому и понадобится немного больше кода -- для создания связи action и label. Впрочем, вы можете и по другому сделать: у action есть методы setData/data вы можете в setData положить label, ну и через data его доставать

Comment: отлично, это то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Контекстное меню `customContextMenuRequested` может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('контекстное меню , customContextMenuRequested')
        self.initUI()

    # окно приложения
    def initUI(self):
        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.textListBox = QVBoxLayout()
        #вызов подгрузки данных в окно приложения
        self.loadDateData()
        verticalBox = QVBoxLayout()
        verticalBox.addLayout(self.textListBox)
        centralWidget.setLayout(verticalBox)
        self.show()

    # подгрузка данных в окно приложения
    def loadDateData(self):
        for n in range(10):
            textLbl = QLabel('text' + str(n))
            textLbl.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
            textLbl.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu)
            # добавление сформированного виджета в QVBoxLayout
            self.textListBox.addWidget(textLbl)

    # отображаем меню при клике на блоке текста
    def on_context_menu(self, *type):
        #print("*type", type)

        menu =QMenu()
        clickableLabel = self.sender().text()

        if clickableLabel == 'text0':
            menu.addAction('Пункт меню 0', self.anyfunction)
        elif clickableLabel == 'text1':
            menu.addAction('Пункт меню 1', self.anyfunction)
        elif clickableLabel == 'text2':
            #menu.addAction('Пункт меню1', self.anyfunction)
            gitMenu=QMenu('Синхронизация с Git', menu)
            self.pushAction = QAction('Загрузить', self, triggered=lambda:self.pr)
            gitMenu.addAction(self.pushAction)
            self.pullAction=QAction('Скачать', self, triggered=lambda:self.pr)
            gitMenu.addAction(self.pullAction)
            gitMenu.addSeparator()
            gitMenu.addAction('Настройка хранилища', lambda: self.pr)
            menu.addAction(gitMenu.menuAction())           # !!
        elif clickableLabel == 'text3':
            menu.addAction('Пункт меню 3', self.anyfunction)
        elif clickableLabel == 'text4':
            menu.addAction('Пункт меню 4', self.anyfunction)
        elif clickableLabel == 'text5':
            menu.addAction('Пункт меню 5', self.anyfunction)
        elif clickableLabel == 'text6':
            menu.addAction('Пункт меню 6', self.anyfunction)
        elif clickableLabel == 'text7':
            menu.addAction('Пункт меню 7', self.anyfunction)
        elif clickableLabel == 'text8':
            menu.addAction('Пункт меню 8', self.anyfunction)
        elif clickableLabel == 'text9':
            menu.addAction('Пункт меню 9', self.anyfunction)            

        menu.addSeparator()  
        menu.exec_(QCursor.pos())        

    def anyfunction(self):  
        print("def anyfunction(self):")   

    def pr(self):        
        print("def pr(self):")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex  = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Пробуйте.

Comment: 1) [customContextMenuRequested](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) всегда передает `pos`, поэтому `*type` можно конкретизировать 2) повторящиеся `self.sender().text()` имеет смысл в одну переменную поместить