# Создание неопределенного числа виджетов PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть список текста, нужно создать, например, Label в определенном количестве, на каждый элемент списка(список динамический), добавить их в VBoxLayout, например, и как то с ними ещё взаимодействовать(контекстное меню накинуть, например).

upd:

```
    for i in minds:
        label = QLabel(self)
        label.setText(i)
        vbox.addWidget(label)
```

Сделал таким образом, но как узнать, это куча разных лэйблов или один, и как можно с ними взаимодействовать?

Comment: `Пытался через while и for, создаётся только один label, в который напихиваются все элементы списка.`, код в студию, скорее всего у вас в одном месте проблема и проще решить только ее, используя ваш код, чем заново все решение писать :)

Comment: Собственно, накидал код, чтобы отправить сюда, а он заработал как надо.

Comment: В [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/885064/pyqt5-реализация-контекстного-меню-у-виджетов-выводимых-через-цикл) вопросе абсолютно всё, что мне нужно.

Comment: Вопрос решен? Если да, опубликуйте пожалуйста ответ, если нет - предоставьте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Предыдущий комментарий был опубликован как ответ, но почему то переведён в комментарий.